# Disable links in Structure Breadcrumb navigation

Tags: structure, navigation, eeharbor

I'm using the Breadcrumbs tag with EE Harbor's Structure module to show people where they are on the site, but I don't want it to have any links. I know, it's a little weird, but that's what the client wants. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!
Porter.